# How many option are there to divide n people into any number of groups of any size?

Tags: combinatorics

I found only something like this:
$$f(0) = 1$$
$$
f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i} * f(i)
$$
Now I wonder if there are other (faster) ways to calculate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the number of [partitions of a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set), or [Bell numbers](http://oeis.org/A000110).